# Apply for UK spouse visa for wife while we both live in Nigeria

Tags: visa, uk-citizens

I am a UK Citizen by birth who moved to Nigeria in the early eighties and would now like to relocate back to the UK with my kids (who have British Passports too) and my wife (who is Nigerian). Would I be able to apply for a spouse visa for my wife while we are both still in Nigeria?

My reasoning behind this is that I want us to relocate together as a family and not have to maintain two disparate homes for her and our children while filing for her visa.

Comment: Related: [British Spouse visa for South African citizen](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/british-spouse-visa-for-south-african-citizen)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Your wife can apply for this visa while you are both in Nigeria.

See https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk.  This explains how to "join family in the UK," but as you can see from the list of qualifying conditions, the family member can also simply be a British citizen:

> Your family member can:
>
> - be a British citizen
> - have settled in the UK
> - have asylum or humanitarian protection in the UK

Comment: Thanks but info in the link says "a partner or family member who’s living in the UK permanently". I currently don't live in the UK but plan to move there shortly.

Comment: @Jigga but the part that I quoted means that if you are a British citizen, you do not need to be living there permanently.  You have the right of abode; that is enough.

Comment: @Jigga have a look at the [immigration rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-8-family-members).  The actual phrase is "persons present and settled in the United Kingdom or being admitted on the same occasion for settlement."  You and your wife would be applying for admission on the same occasion for settlement.